# Method to determine index of parent loop when child loop matches condition

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, nested-loops

EDIT: As Damien_The_Unbeliever stated, to make the question easier to understand, the end result is trying to "search a sequence for a subsequence". Find the sequence of `Blue,Yellow,Green` from `colorsToFind` within `colorList`

Does anyone have some pointers as to determine the best way to have nested for loops where the inner loop needs to determine is a sequence of strings is contained in the parent loop?

So for the example below, since "Blue", "Yellow", "Green" would be found at indexes [5], [6], [7] I would want to return those indexes. Or at least the first found index of [5].

I think that the problem has to do with how the `for (int j` loop is breaking out on found indexes.

```
string[] colorList = "Royal Blue", "Tomato Red", "Mustard Yellow", "Midnight Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Red", "Evergreen", "Purple", "Black", "Jet Black";

string name = "Blue,Yellow,Green";

string[] colorsToFind = name.Split(',');
int found = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < colorList.Count -1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < colorsToFind.Count; j++)
    {
        if (colorList[i] == colorsToFind[j])
        {
            found = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if(found != 0)
{
    return found;
}

return null;
```

Comment: Also if they are found you are not capturing all of the indexed positions in the array where i found = true. you could add the found values to a List<int> or List<string> within the inner loop..

Comment: So, a clearer way of stating this might be that you want to search a sequence for a subsequence? (Presumably, without any intermediate non-matching elements, but that's not clear from your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string[] colorList = {"Royal Blue", "Tomato Red", "Mustard Yellow", "Midnight Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Red", "Evergreen", "Purple", "Black", "Jet Black"};
string[] colorsToFind = "Blue,Yellow,Green".Split(',');

for (int i = 0; i < colorList.Length - colorsToFind.Length; i++)
{
    int j;  // we'll need this later
    for (j = 0; j < colorsToFind.Length; j++)
    {
        if (colorList[j + i] != colorsToFind[j])
        {
            break;  // stop if it doesn't match
        }
    }

    // j for-loop was exited because j == colorsToFind.Length so a set matched
    if (j == colorsToFind.Length)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I feel like this was the key `if (colorList[j + i]`

Answer (score 0):

You are testing for equality, when you mean to compare occurrence.

```
if (colorList[i].indexOf(colorsToFind[j]) != -1)
{
    found = i;
    break;
}
```

Comment: I think this would be similar to the comment I left for Dave Zych as indexOf would find Blue in `Royal Blue` which would be seen as a false positive

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < colorList.Count -3; i++)
{
     if (colorList[i] == colorsToFind[0] && 
         colorList[i+1] == colorsToFind[1] && 
         colorList[i+2] == colorsToFind[2])
     {
            found = i;
            break;
     }
}

for (int i = 0; i < colorList.Count - colorsToFind.count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < colorsToFind.Count; j++)
    {
        bool match = true;
        if (colorList[i+j] != colorsToFind[j])
        {
            match = false;
        }  
    }
    if (match) 
    {   
        found = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now think what would happen if colorsToFind added `Red` :/

Comment: @jmfsg Then I think you would build on this.